# OpenGLES Matrix optimization

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm rendering 100+ 3D objects in OpenGLES and I wondered if this standard matrix code can be optimized for improved performance speed:

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
    Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix,  0, scale,scale,1.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
```

The objects are all scaled, rotated and positioned in different ways and my app is running too slow. I am looking in to many other areas, but the profiler shows this code as quite a performance hit, so can the maths be done any faster?

Any tips, much appreciated.

Comment: What does optimised mean? Quicker? Less code? Better rendering? What isn't your code currently doing that you need it to? How do _you_ think you might get to where you need to be?

Comment: Added some clarification to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3725725 - I'm assuming you're using column vectors

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);

// Set up the scale 
modelMatrix[0] = scale;
modelMatrix[5] = scale;

// Set up Translation 
modelMatrix[12] = tx; 
modelMatrix[13] = ty;
modelMatrix[14] = tz;

// Do the rest of the matrix multiplication 
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
```

PS. If this helped, consider an up-vote :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may gain much by feeding the matrix value directly losing the translate, scale and rotate calls. The rotate call can be very slow...

The matrix starting 3x3 sub matrix consists of the 3 base vectors (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) which can be set as (in the example you posted):

```
X = (cos(angle)*scale, sin(angle)*scale, .0f)
Y = (-sin(angle)*scale, cos(angle)*scale, .0f)
Z = (.0f, .0f, 1.0f)
```

Note: the order depends on the implementation

Next either 4th row or column (depends on the order implementation again) is in your case the translation:

```
T = (x, y, z, 1.0f)
```

This alone will not gain you any performance at all as there are 4 expensive trigonometry calls (the `sin` and `cos`) which are also used in `rotate`. If possible try to lose the angle parameter and replace it with a `way` vector which is the vector the object is facing toward. A standard is to also include the `up` vector which is the vector facing up from the object. Having these 2 vectors you can then compute the `right` vector using a cross product of previous two. The result is having 3 perpendicular vectors which should be normalized and multiplied with scale then directly inserted into the matrix as the 3 base vectors mentioned above.

In your case you can get one direction and as your `Z` vector seems to be static you may use a cross product on those two to get the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your matrix multiplication can be written as:

Result = ITSR.

For every matrix multiplication (and I'm assuming the matrices are 4x4), you've got 64 multiplications and 64 additions. And now you've got 4 matrices that you're multiplying out. That's a lot of additions and multiplications!  Let's assume you're using column vectors.

To speed things up, do the following:

The Translation matrix will only have values in the last (4th) column. So when you multiply IxT, the resulting matrix will still only have values in the 4th column.  So to speed things up, just create a matrix with the 4th column being the translation vector, like this, instead of doing the full matrix multiplication:

```
So, we have IT =  | 1 0 0 0 |  | 1 0 0 tx |   | 1 0 0 tx |
                  | 0 1 0 0 |  | 0 1 0 ty | = | 0 1 0 ty |
                  | 0 0 1 0 |  | 0 0 1 tz |   | 0 0 1 tz |
                  | 0 0 0 1 |  | 0 0 0  1 |   | 0 0 0  1 |
```

Moving onto ITxS, since scaling only affects the diagonal - it only affects elements m[0][0], m[1][1] and m[2][2], you can simply multiply these elements of the matrix by the scale.  So we'll have:

```
Sx = m[0][0] * scale;
Sy = m[1][1] * scale;
Sz = m[2][2] * 1.0;
```

But, since all the diagonal elements in IT are 1, you can just write the scale value into the diagonal… like this:

```
ITS = | Sx  0   0  tx |
      | 0  Sy   0  ty |
      | 0   0  Sz  tz |
      | 0   0   0  1  |
```

So up to this point, we didn't perform any matrix multiplications - we just created the matrix by hand. So you can just create a matrix that looks like ITS. This saves you 2 matrix multiplications!!

Now moving onto ITSR … here, just do the standard matrix multiplication as:

```
Result = ITSR = | Sx  0   0  tx |  | A  D  G  0 |
                | 0  Sy   0  ty |  | B  E  H  0 |
                | 0   0  Sz  tz |  | C  F  I  0 |
                | 0   0   0  1  |  | 0  0  0  1 |
```

You could speed it up slightly, but for clarity, just do full matrix multiplication.  So you only need to do a single matrix multiplication, instead of 3.

Also, if your camera view does not change (the viewMatrix), you don't have to derive it for each frame, and the same goes for the projection matrix. I don't know if you do … just saying.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this. My camera does not move, so how would I optimize the view matrix?

Comment: @user3725725 Well, the view matrix is derived using the LookAt() function, as far as I remember, but bottom line, once that matrix is created, you don't have to recreate it for each frame. You pass it into your vertex shader as a uniform -- and you pass it in just once. The vertex shader will hang onto that matrix even if you make another program active, then go back to this one. By the way, look at my blog [www.thecodecrate.com](http://www.thecodecrate.com), I've posted a few OpenGLES posts there concerning matrices… thanks. Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: Cool. What would my original code look like now after making the suggested improvements? Thanks.